# Characteristics of continuous maps with double-point

Tags: algebraic-topology, continuity, fixed-point-theorems

By the Borsuk-Ulam theorem we know that every continuous map $M:S^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ has a point in its range that is the image of two points in domain. by considering this I am curious to see what amount of this double point would exist for such maps and what we can say about the set of points in the range which are the image of one or odd number of points in the domain for all maps.

It is known that for every continuous Non one element range map $f_1:S^1\to \mathbb{R}$ there are properties which state that for an even $e\in \mathbb{N}$ the set of points in its range which their preimage have exactly $e$ points is uncountable and for evey odd $o\in \mathbb{N}$ the *o- point* set in codomain $\mathbb{R}$ has [countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3468191/set-of-odd-points-of-continuous-maps-s1-to-mathbbr/3468322#3468322) elements.

Also intuition says something similar but more complex about two dimension continuous maps $f_2:S^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ which the dimension of $f_2(S^2)$ is $2$ (the same as codomain $\mathbb{R}^2$ dimension).
It states that the *o-point* sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$ which $o\in \mathbb{N}$ is odd have one dimentional loop structure and for at least on even $e\in \mathbb{N}$ the *e-point* set has a two dimensional disc structure for each of its connected components.

**Questions**:

First: can anyone present more rigorous statements about the latter case above?(with proof)

Second :In general does there any invariant of the continuous maps relating to aggregation of characteristics info (structure, size, dimension ,...) of *$n$-point* ($\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$) and *uncount-point* sets of the map?

**Note:** *$n$-point* set for a map $f:X\to Y$ is the set of all points such  $p\in Y$ that the preimage $f^{-1}(\{p\})$ consists of exactly $n$ points in $X$, if the preimage $f^{-1}(\{p\})$ consist of uncountable points in the domain then we call it a *uncount-point*.

Comment: Your "obvious" statement about $f_1$ is wrong; for instance, consider a map which loops back and forth between two points many times.

Comment: @EricWofsey you're true ,I haven't consider that special case, but still the second question  should be investigated for this simple example ,I think the *n-point* set of $f_1$ for at least one odd $n$ is countable.